# ListView displays certain images but won't display others

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to get certain images to display on the side of the scrolling item list created by ListView.

Right now I'm using the data template from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780650.aspx

```
<Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="110" Height="110">
<Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

With Item being a property that is set as follows

```
if(Type.ToLower().CompareTo("success") == 0)
                    _image = "/Assets/Ok_16.png";
                else
                    _image = "/Assets/Error_16.png";
```

So basically if a process was successful, it displays one image, and another if it fails.  Right now only the error image will display.  I put both of them in the Assets folder and checked the filenames so I don't understand why it won't display the other image.  I tried the generic images like Logo.png and they work fine, but when I created a copy of Logo.png and called it Logo1.png, it wouldn't display it.

Any ideas on what could be happening?

Comment: Make sure your png files have their `build action` set to `resouce` in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: It appears that the files that won't work don't show up in the solution explorer.  They're in the right folder though, so how can I make solution explorer recognize them?

Comment: right click project -> add existing item -> select your files -> click OK -> put them in the correct folder -> set build action to `Resource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer:

`right click project -> add existing item -> select your files -> click OK -> put them in the correct folder -> set build action to Resource`